# Rails : Is there any good reference/tutorials/guides for routing of nested resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, resources, routes, nested

Is there any good reference for routing of nested resources ?

For eg -

For a singular resource

```
resources:photos
```

The various paths are :

```
photos_path returns /photos
new_photo_path returns /photos/new
edit_photo_path(id) returns /photos/:id/edit (for instance, edit_photo_path(10) returns /photos/10/edit)
photo_path(id) returns /photos/:id (for instance, photo_path(10) returns /photos/10)
```

What are similar paths for answers as  routed below ?

```
resources :chapters do
     resources :questions do
       resources :answers
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just run

```
rake routes
```

and it will list all your routes

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the "Rails Routing from the Outside In" guide? I find it explains nested resources pretty well:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: The guide doesnt clearly mention the parameters of all the methods. It says - "These helpers take an instance of Magazine as the first parameter" . However no clue if any of the methods need more parameters or so.